# mysql db types for queue simulation

Tags: mysql, queue, innodb, myisam

I am simulating several instruction queues using a mysql table.  There is a 'mode' column which is the name for each queue and once items are taken from the queue they are deleted right afterwards. Typical queries look like

```
SELECT * FROM queue_table WHERE mode='queue1' LIMIT 50.
```

I am currently using a `MYISAM` table for this but there is a lot of overhead with all the deleting and optimization takes a long time.  I was just wondering if there was a more efficient way to do this and if maybe the database should be `INNODB`.

Comment: How long these queues expected to live?

Comment: The queue itself will live indefinitely but an individual member should pass through the queues within 2-3 days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`InnoDB` are useful if your are implying *Foreign key constraints* .
so one thing for optimizing you Query..

create index on`mode` column and also dont use `*` ( may be your table have a lots of columns), write column name which you only need to retrive.

Comment: Well I am not linking between any other tables... I just need to know which one is quick for inserting and deleting without too much overhead.  Thanks for the tip about using the column names... but there are only about 3 non-index columns and one index column besides the mode.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say I completely understand your problem but I am sure that if you will make your fileds of fixed size (i.e. no `text` fields, `char` instead of `varchar`) the table records become extremely reusable and require no optimization at all.

Comment: I think the optimization comes in because there is a lot of inserting and deleting so the indices in the MYISAM have to be 'defragged' so to speak.  But thanks I will get rid of everything which isn't fixed length.